# How do i get the values from leerling lower than 10?

Tags: c#

```
class Leerling
{


    public int Leeftijd { get; set; }
    public decimal Cijfer { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public List<Leerling> Studentenlijst { get; set; }

    public Leerling()
    {
        Studentenlijst = new List<Leerling>();
    }

    public Leerling(int _leeftijd, int _cijfer, string _naam, string _achternaam)
    {
        Leeftijd = _leeftijd;
        Cijfer = _cijfer;
        Naam = _naam;
        Achternaam = _achternaam;

    }

    public string ToonLeerling()
    {
        string output = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < Studentenlijst.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Studentenlijst[i].Leeftijd <= 14)
            {
                Leerling objLeerling = (Leerling)Studentenlijst[i];
                output = output + objLeerling.ToString();


            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    public string ToonLeerlingouder()
    {
        string output = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < Studentenlijst.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Studentenlijst[i].Leeftijd >= 15
                )
            {
                Leerling objLeerling = (Leerling)Studentenlijst[i];
                output = output + objLeerling.ToString();

            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    public void addLeerling()
    {
        Leerling Leerling1 = new Leerling(18, 60, "Tom", "Lub");
        Leerling Leerling2 = new Leerling(14, 50, "Kees", "Apenvlees");

        Studentenlijst.Add((Leerling)Leerling1);
        Studentenlijst.Add((Leerling)Leerling2);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return " Leeftijd " + Leeftijd + "\n Cijfer: " + Cijfer + "\n Naam: " + Naam + "\n Achternaam: " + Achternaam;
    }

/*

  Leerling l = new Leerling();

            l.addLeerling();
            Console.WriteLine(l.ToonLeerling().ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

            l.addLeerling();
            Console.WriteLine(l.ToonLeerlingouder().ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

*/
}
```

}

How do I get the values of `leerling` below 10?

Comment: @elgonzo because without the copy and pasted last sentence, SO doesn't let the question be posted because the question has too much code and not enough context.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Didn't know that. Deleted my former comment. Thanks @DannyGoodall!

Comment: This feels like a school exercise, so I'm wondering what kind of constraints you're working with. Are you allowed to use any more advanced language constructs or are only for-loops and if-statements allowed? The reason I'm asking is that there's quite a few higher level concepts that vastly simplify your code, but it means you won't learn about the lower level concepts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public List<String> ToonLeerlingJonger(){
    List<String> LeerlingenJongerDan10 = new List<String>();

    foreach(Leerling l in Studentenlijst){
        if(l.Leeftijd < 10){
            LeerlingenJongerDan10.add(l.ToString());
        }

    return LeerlingenJongerDan10;
    }
}
```